# Azure AD OIDC ID Token for Service Principal

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

Is it possible to obtain an OAuth2 id_token for an Azure AD Service Principal?

I can go through the client_credentials flow against the /token endpoint, but that only yields an access_token. Is there a way for me to get an id_token as well, like I do for an interactive user?

Comment: how you get access_token with code?

Comment: Just by making a simple HTTP POST request against the /token endpoint with the parameters for a client_credentials flow...but that only yields an access_token...I want/need an id_token (too)

Comment: @Jeff, can you please elaborate on which user this ID Token would be identifying? In all specified OpenID Connect flows, an ID Token is used to identify the *user*, and hence is only relevant for flows which involve a user.

Answer (score 0):

No. You need to go through a flow which involves a service principal *and a user*.

Client credentials flow only involves the service principal, so the access token only contains its info. Id tokens are only given when there is a user context.

So, for an Id token, you need to use one of these flows:

- Authorization Code
- Implicit
- Device code
- On-Behalf-Of (API calling another API)
- Resource Owner Password (though I don't recommend this one)

Ultimately, why do you need an Id token? The access token already contains who the calling app is. It should contain an `appid` claim, which is the client Id for the app.

Comment: I need an id token because I have another service (AWS) set up with AAD as an external IdP (via OIDC not SAML). In order for me to sign on to AWS programmatically in this setup, I need to give it an id_token issued by AAD, not an access_token. Consider the following example - it’s for Okta and AWS, but the idea is the same...how would I accomplish this with just a Service Principal?

Comment: With a setup like that, the IdP there should be redirecting the user to login at the external IdP (AAD here) by using the OpenID Connect protocol. Then your IdP there would receive the id token in the response.

Comment: Right but in this case the external idp IS azure ad. It’s the example from my link but instead of Okta, it’s Azure AD. So hence I need an id_token for the service Principal in azure ad or can you suggest an alternative? This is a non interactive scenario

Comment: In a non-interactive scenario your only choice would be either using a refresh token or by using username and password with the ROPC flow. Both of these cases give you an id token for a user, though ROPC is not recommended, and won't work in some situations. It is not possible to get an id token for the service principal alone.

Comment: How would a refresh token work in this scenario and how can I get one from AAD?

Comment: Ah, actually I did now remember you don't get an Id token in either of those. You only get an Id token with authorization code, implicit, and device code flows. And all of those are interactive.

Comment: So the only thing to do is to create a "dummy" user and have the SP use that instead?

Comment: @Jeff Did you try using the access token? I haven't had a chance to look into this in detail, it, but the AWS docs suggest that either an OpenID Connect ID Token or an OAuth 2.0 Access Token would work: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/WebIdentityCredentials.html

Comment: yes I had tried....buuuuuuttt the access token doesn’t have a sub claim (probably because it’s a Service Principal?) ...and that’s the claim AWS looks for when you give it a token for a WebIdentityCredential.